# Concatenating the Two cells but the value sequence is not accurate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to concatenate two cells but the result is not accurate. I have attached a Sheet if someone could help me.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried with 2 formulas.

```
=G2&" "&H2

=TEXTJOIN(char(10),TRUE,IF(F2=A2:A92,C2:C92,""))&" "&TEXTJOIN(char(10),TRUE,IF(F2=A2:A92,(B2:B92*100)&"%",""))
```

But result is not accurate result should be like

```
Requirements 100%
Meet Client 0%
Requirements 100%
Process 20%
Configure server 0%
```

But my results come in that way which is wrong

```
Meet Client
Requirements
Process
Configure server 0%
100%
20%
0%"
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14q2Nh3Q7dtrgKWohllXdKXYSz3kDRKqVLaw9ijPmTdQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&" "&TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),"0%"))
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) Q&A about how to use `FILTERXML()` to split data in Excel (2013+).

---

**EDIT:**

In case you have a version of Excel prior to Excel 2019 you won't have access to `TEXTJOIN()` and your best bet would be to create an UDF (User Defined Function) through VBA to mimic the desired behaviour. I threw together a quick example below:

```
Function JOIN2ARRAYS(x As String, y As String, z As String) As String

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, i As Long
arr1 = Split(x, z)
arr2 = Split(y, z)

For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    If JOIN2ARRAYS = "" Then
        JOIN2ARRAYS = arr1(i) & " " & arr2(i)
    Else
        JOIN2ARRAYS = JOIN2ARRAYS & z & arr1(i) & " " & arr2(i)
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Call this in your sheet with `=JOIN2ARRAYS(A1,B1,CHAR(10))`

Comment: Thank you very very much @JvdV

Comment: If it does not bother you can you please share that how to apply this on Microsoft Excel 2016 @JvdV

Comment: @Mento, `TEXTJOIN()` is a function only available since Excel 2019 and would require a CSE-entering. In Microsoft365 this is done automatically. For Excel2016 you cannot use the above solution.

Comment: Yes i have been tried it at home where it was working fine but in office i have MS 2016 where its not working. I hope there can be other solution as well or should i post new question.

Comment: @Mento, it is definately supposed to be a new question but I happen to have Excel2016 at work and threw together a quick example. See the edit above.